# "Now that we got to know each other" vs "now that we know each other"

Tags: phrase-choice

Let's say I got a new group of students, I told them who I am, my name, and they did the same. Would it be appropriate to say the following?

> Now that we **know** each other, let's get started with class.
>
> Now that we **get to know** each other, let's get started with class.

Is there any difference between the sentences? By the way, would be better to say *let's get started with the lesson*?

Comment: Now that we have been [introduced](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/introduced), ...

Comment: Is it correct to say "let's get intriduced to each other"? Does that sound natural?

Comment: No, better to say "let's introduce ourselves".

Comment: What if I add "to each other", for example: "Let's introduce outself to each other", would it sound natural as well?

Comment: The title of your question uses *got* but the body of your question uses *get*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is fine.*

If you want to use the second sentence, you need to correct the tense.

The action of *getting to know each other* has been completed, so you should not use the present tense (***get*** to know). Since the action has just been completed, you should use the present perfect:

*Now that we **have got** to know each other...*

Or, in American English:

*Now that we **have gotten** to know each other...*

---

* Some might say that learning someone's name is not the same as *knowing* the person - which typically involves learning more and more personal information about the person.

Comment: Isn't **gotten** a bit colloquial? "Now that we have **got** to know each other."

Comment: @WeatherVane, it's normal in American English.  Would you say "we have got to know each other" in British English?

Comment: The view from here is in every English dialect except US country dialect.

Comment: Interesting.  It's Standard American. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/difference-between-i-have-got-and-i-have-gottentrump.html

Comment: Hm, Robusto's answer to that question says "As for *gotten*, I see no harm in using it informally..."

Comment: I suppose it depends on what "informally" means. *Get to know* (likewise, *get good at* in Robusto's answer) is not exactly formal language, in any tense. In this case, if I wanted to be very formal, I might say, "Now that we have become acquainted." But "have gotten" is formal enough for an American newspaper of record: ["America’s Skies Have Gotten Clearer, but Millions Still Breathe Unhealthy Air"](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/06/19/climate/us-air-pollution-trump.html)

Comment: And here's one with "have gotten to know": https://www.nytimes.com/2018/09/15/travel/ursa-minor-lopez-island-washington-restaurant-review.html

Comment: I know it is used, but I doubt the credentials of the speaker in your first link ;(